# Cannot find group photos using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to download all the photos from an old secret facebook group I was in a few years ago.  I still am in the group and wanted to use the API to pull all the wall posts and photos.

I was able to get all the wall posts from the feed but I am having trouble finding the photos.

I think one issue is that none of the photos are in any albums, they are all just under the photo tab.  None of the options I have tried under the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer have shown me any of the photos.  This group was created back in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this for a similar project. Each photo is associated to a post, and is accessible from group/feed endpoint at the same time you are getting wall posts by accessing the 'full_picture' field.

It's easiest to see this directly in the Graph API Explorer. Once you've gotten a token with adequate permissions, you can enter a group ID into the command line, then specify the feed endpoint and the fields you'd like returned.

For example, to return: post date, user, message/caption, and photo URL (if one exists), you would submit something like this  (with the group ID swapped out for yours):

[image: screencap of Graph API Explorer]

and the resulting output will look something like this:

[image: screencap of Graph API output]
you can then call that full_picture url to download the image-  fb expires the image URLs pretty quickly, so it's not enough to just save the URL.

Of course, in your program you'll also have to pass in a authorization token and navigate all the pagination etc, etc. But if you've already gotten past those obstacles, this should be straightforward.